# Hibernate: How can i resolve java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

This is my first Hibernate practice, I got the following Error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/CallbackFilter
```

I added the jar file to project library but the error still remains. I am using Eclipse.

How can i Solve this problem, Is this related to my code ? or about Settings in Eclipse ?

This is my hibernate example

[This is my hibernate example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm)

[hibernate configuration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm)

Errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/CallbackFilter
at org.hibernate.bytecode.cglib.BytecodeProviderImpl.getProxyFactoryFactory(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:33)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactoryInternal(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:182)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:160)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:269)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:425)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1218)
at com.hib.anoop.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.CallbackFilter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
```

I have added the correct jar,the  problem solved, But  new problem occured as following

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: That error means it can't find the class on your classpath. You may have added it to the project, but are you sure your classpath is set up properly when you run? Are you running within the IDE or a packaged jar file?

Comment: i am using Eclipse, and run as java application, jar file added to library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, the problem was related to the versions of jar file `cglib` and `asm`.

Now, I am replaced the jars with `cglib 2.2.2` and `asm 3.3.1`

Now, Mismatch is solved and got output.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include cglib jar in your classpath?

I think that is the problem here.

You can dowload from here:

https://github.com/cglib/cglib/releases

Answer (score 0):

You need cgLib on your classpath, if you are using maven you can download it from here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-cglib-repack/2.1_3 .

This class is used by hibernate to create proxy objects on your lazy relations to other entities, you can read more about it here:

http://java-success.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-hibernate-proxy-objects.html

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after adding maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
  <version>2.1_3</version>
</dependency>
```